# How to assign a minimum value for parameters in a constructor (java)?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

For instance, I have a constructor:

```
public Employee(int age, String name){ }
```

Which command should I write in the constructor that it doesn't allow to create an employee object with the age parameter less than 21?

I am not allowed to use exceptions.

Thank you

Comment: You should tell us what the constructor should do in case the argument is less than 21.

Comment: have the check before calling constructor

Answer (score 4):

Write something like this:

```
public Employee(int age, String name) {
    if (age < 21) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "expected age to be greater than or equal to 21, but was " + age);
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use exceptions, I am sorry that I didn't mention that.

Comment: @user3371414 That is the right way to do it though... What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: @user3371414 there is no other way to avoid object-creation

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Employee {

    private Employee(int age, String name) throws Exception {
    //Your code
    }

   public static Employee getInstance(int age, String name){
        if(age >= 21){
        return new Employee(age,name);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
   }    

}
```

// Now to create object call getInstance()

Comment: @Juvanis Constructor must be private

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **static factory method** and make the constructor private.
Then within that method I would control those values to create an instance or not.

```
public static Employee getInstance(int age, String name)
{
   if(age >= 21)
      return new Employee(age, name);
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Is that really necessary?!

Comment: @assylias not necessary but it is an alternative.

Comment: I would do the same. It is more flexible I guess.

Comment: Could you please explain me how does that work? It looks so confusing to me. Thank you once again

Comment: @user3371414 user Ajit stole my answer, you can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom exception for this condition

```
class AgeException extends Exception
{

      public AgeExceptionException() {}


 }


try
 {
     if(age< 21)
     {
          throw new AgeExceptionException();
     }
 }
 catch(AgeExceptionException ex)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to enforce this without explicitly throwing an error you could use an assert.

```
public Employee(int age, String name){
    // Age higher than 21?
    assert(age > 21);

    /* Code */
}
```

You will have to enable asserts though with -ea as build option, otherwise they don't work.